# Rapid prototyping and development of business applications

Tags: database, language-agnostic, crud, informix, rapid-prototyping

Thirty years ago, when I began to design and develop CRUD business applications, I envisioned that as time moved on, designing, prototyping and customizing business applications would become easier and more streamlined. In 1983, I discovered a simple, easy-to-use RDBMS called INFORMIX which enabled me to quickly define schemas, generate default, character-based CRUD forms and reports which could be quickly and easily customized to get an app up and running in a very short timeframe. When GUI front-ends and OOP langs started to make their appearance, I was under the impression that developing apps was going to be even faster and effortless, but to my disappointment, it has become more complex and time-consuming! What can be accomplished with one 4GL instruction can take several hundred lines of code with OOPL's. I have looked at several development environments and tools within the sea of products currently out there and have not been able to find a good Windows/GUI-based 4GL product which can quickly generate default screens and reports where I can then customize into a final product without it taking a long time to accomplish. I recently eval'd 4J's Genero Development Suite where I even encountered bugs/obstacles in getting the demo's to work!.. It feels like everything got more time-consuming and complicated when it was supposed to be the other way around!..

Does an easy-to-use, GUI/RDBMS-based rapid development system exist out there which can provide me a simple/fast way for developing CRUD apps?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which RDBMS and development tool should I choose to re-write my character-based app? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340685/which-rdbms-and-development-tool-should-i-choose-to-re-write-my-character-based-a)

Comment: Also similar is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360786/looking-for-a-sql-based-rdbms-with-a-windows-gui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filemaker will likely provide you with everything you've asked for here.  It's easy to use, cost effective.  http://www.filemaker.com and you can download a 30 day trial there as well.

There are a lot of people who will give FM grief, but the most recent version is a very solid product.  Works on Windows and Mac.  Good luck.

Comment: Filemaker Pro (Advanced) demo looks good so far!.. I've heard mixed reviews about this product. Is it truly capabale of delivering sophisticated business applications?

Comment: Yes, it is.  There are lots of applications in use written in Filemaker and it continues to be a living platform (they just released iphone and ipad versions, too).    The mixed reviews are often from people who don't understand what niche it fills.

Comment: OK, well I'm going to judge the product based on my own experience when I eval it. My app is mainly single-user for small mom-n-pop pawnshops in Puerto Rico ( see video-demo at: www.frankcomputer.com ) and although it has comprehensive/sophisticated functionality, it doesnt have a high-volume of transactions or large tables. Im looking for a quick way of re-writting it mainly for providing a Win/GUI frontend while retaining existing functionality.

Comment: Filemaker is perfect for that.  The 'advanced' version of Filemaker has the ability to output stand alone applications and kiosk-type applications.

Comment: Ok then we shall see!.. It is my understanding that FMP's data manipulation language is not SQL-based (confirm?) however if I'm able to achieve my goals of quickly re-writing my current app with an FMP-based GUI, then so be it!

Comment: You are correct: FMP is not SQL based (though it is relational).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Oracle Application Express](http://apex.oracle.com). Also works with the free Oracle Express Edition (XE) database.